# How to ignore specific metadata using ignore_changes block?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

The thing is I know Terraform `ignore_changes` block only supports static lists or in another words, static indices mapping to items. Secondly, I need to be able to ignore specific metadata based on a regex.

I tried to use a local value and then use it in a list but it returned with the same error.

```
 locals {
   ignore_gke_metadata_changes = [
     for x in google_compute_project_metadata.metadata.metadata : x.key if regex("^gke-dku[0-9]+$", x.key)
   ]
 }

 lifecycle {
   ignore_changes = local.ignore_gke_metadata_changes
 }
```

Edit:

Here's a sample of the error returned when I try to run a plan:

```
16:     ignore_changes = local.ignore_gke_metadata_changes
 
A static list expression is required.
```

Comment: You cannot do that: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/lifecycle#literal-values-only.

Comment: @MarkoE Okayy so there's no way or even a workaround to iterate over a list and pass it statically to the lifecycle block?

Comment: I don't think so.